# Looping through Linest Functions VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns of independent variables (MSCI's) follow by columns of dependant variables (no set number)  like so:

```
MSCI Growth  MSCI Value MSCI Small Cap     Fund A    Fund B  Fund C  etccc
xxx           yyyy         zzzz                xxx     yyyy  zzz        
xxx           yyyy         zzzz                xxx     yyyy  zzzz
xxx           yyyy         zzzz                xxx     yyyy  zzzz
xxx           yyyy         zzzz                xxx     yyyy  zzzz
xxx           yyyy         zzzz
xxx           yyyy         zzzz
xxx           yyyy         zzzz
```

I need to use the Linest Function to regress each independent variable against each dependent and tabulate the values of results.  I will always have 3 independent variables but a variable number of dependent variables (funds)

My problems are as follows:

1) The following data will produce 9 values of results (slope of each of the lines).  I want to put these into a table, can I write this into the loop or will it have to be done seperately? Example results table

```
      MSCI Growth  MSCI Value MSCI Small Cap
Fund A  Coeff       Coeff      Coeff
Fund B  Coeff       Coeff      Coeff
Fund C  Coeff       Coeff      Coeff
```

2) Some Funds do not have the same number of rows as the MSCIs (independent variable) if this is the case, the linest function will not work, but I will need to produce an error message in the table and continue onto the next fund.  I am unsure how to reflect this in the loop.

I have a Linest function that works and have set my ranges for each independant variable

```
Sub NestedLoops()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim gRange As Range

Set StartCell = Range("B9")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set gRange = Range(StartCell, Cells(LastRow, 2)) 'range for MSCI Growth
Set vRange = Range("c9", Cells(LastRow, 3)) 'range for MSCI value
Set cRange = Range("D9", Cells(LastRow, 4)) 'range for MSCI small Cap


Range("M13").value = Application.LinEst(gRange, Range("G9:G112"))
```

From here I am unsure where to go in terms of writing the nested loop.  Ideally, I would like the Range ("G9:"G112") to increment the column number by one each time - perform the Linest if it has the same number of rows of data, produce an error message if not - tabulate the resuts and move onto the next fund. 
Repeat this process until the columns are empty (no more funds).  And start over but using the next independent variable (vRange).

Any help/ advice on the best/ most efficient way to go about this task would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in lieu of using a name range try using offset method of range object to move across columns